# Finding midpoint of array in MIPS - Merge sort

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mergesort

I'm trying to create a merge sort algorithm in MIPS and I've identified a bug in my code. In my program, I'm keeping references to the start point and end point of my array (`$a0` and `$a1` respectively). I'm also keeping track of its length as `$a1 - $a0 + 4`. The problem is that I don't know how to calculate the midpoint of the array correctly. I need to do so for these equivalent function calls in C:

```
mergesort(a, start, mid);
mergesort(a, mid + 1, end);
```

I'm new to MIPS so I'm not exactly sure how you do the arithmetic with 4-bit addresses. I can't add them as `($a0 + $a1)/2` since adding two addresses will cause overflow.

My array is declared up on top as this:

```
array: .word 0:15
```

I can assume that not more than 15 numbers will be entered. `$s0` (the pointer to the start of the array), `$s1` (the pointer to the space AFTER the last element), `$a0` (the starting point argument), and `$a1` (the end point argument) are all stored like this:

```
la $s0, array
move $s1, $s0 // $s1 increments by 4 each time an element is added
...
move $a0, $s0
addi $a1, $s1, -4 // subtract four because we want to refer to the last element
```

How can I calculate the mid index of that array given $a0 and $a1 as references? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`($a0 + $a1) / 2 = $a0 + ($a1 - $a0) / 2` and you won't have any overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about intermediate overflow. Just use unsigned addition (without overflow) and then shift right one bit to divide by two:

```
  addu $a2, $a0, $a1  # $a0 and $a1 hold start and end addresses
  srl $a2, $a2, 1     # $a2 holds mid address
```